# Solve $u_{xx} + u_{ yy} = 0\,\,$ in the disk $\{r < a\}\,\,$, with the boundary condition $u = 1 + 3 \sin θ$ on $r = a$.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, poissons-equation

> Solve $u_{xx} + u_{ yy} = 0$ in the disk $\{r < a\}$ with the boundary condition $u = 1 + 3 \sin θ\,$ on $\,r = a.$

In this example, writer says that the full Fourier series for $h(\theta )=1+3\sin\theta$,  $A_0=2, B_1=3/a$, and all other coefficients are $0$. How does he finds these?

Then he concludes that $u(r,\theta)=1+\frac 3 {a}r\sin\theta.$

In rectangular coordinates $u(x,y)=1+\frac {3y} {a}$

> Here are the formulas we need (Poison's Formula):
>
> $$u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0,   \quad x^2+y^2\lt a^2$$
> $$ u=h(\theta),\quad x^2+y^2= a^2  $$
> $$ u=\frac 1 2A_0+\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n [A_n\cos(n\theta)B_n\sin (n\theta)] $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed:

$$\frac 1 2A_0+\sum_{n=1}^\infty a^n (A_n\cos {n\theta}+B_n\sin {n\theta})=1+3\sin(\theta)$$

implies that:

$$\frac{A_0}{2}=1 \quad\text{and} \quad \sum_{n=1}^\infty a^nA_n\cos(n\theta)=0 \quad \text{and} \quad \sum_{n=1}^\infty a^nB_n\sin(n\theta)=3\sin(\theta)$$

Then $A_n=0 $ for all $n>0$. And

$$aB_1\sin(\theta)+a^2B_2\sin(2\theta)+a^3B_3\sin(3\theta)+\ldots=3\sin(\theta)$$

Hence $aB_1=3$ and the others terms are zero.

Comment: I believe that $a_n$ is $a^n$, thus you need to write it in your solution instead $a$ inside the series.

Comment: You're right, I have edited. Thanks.

Comment: I don't remember well this theory, I think that your reasoning for deduce $A_0$ and $B_n$'s is right. But I think that in your reasoning for the $A_n$'s with $n\geq 1$, you need to invoke the integral representation and ortogonality.